# Nested Relationships

Tags: views

I have three content types: A, B and C. C references B (one to many) and B references A (one to many). Each content type has a *Title* field; A also has a *Type* field.

I want to output the titles of all the nodes from a C node, where *Type* in an A node is equal to *XY*. I don't seem to be able to set up relationships in view for B -> A.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think the Views module lets you set a relationship like that, from the entity being listed to another entity that is referred from an entity that is referred from the first entity.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear.I don't understand what you want.
But I think it can help you.
[Node relationship](https://drupal.org/project/noderelationships)

Comment: If you are on drupal 7 you can test https://drupal.org/project/er

Comment: The OP is asking about setting up a relationship in view. _Relationship_ is a very specific view term that has nothing to share with the module you are linking. Link-only answers are not considered answers, on Stack Exchange.